# How different is making changes in soft proofing from print adjustments in LR?

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing, printing

In LR, see there are two ways to edit pictures intended for print. One is print adjustments in the Print section where you could change the brightness and contrast. The other is by making changes after switching on soft proofing in the develop section.

I intend to print my pictures but not directly but after importing them into some magazine layout into InDesign. So I suppose, the Print section wouldn't work for me. So only the soft proof option is left for me. What I ask is the changes done in both - are they the same, or is something different between the two?

Answer (score 1):

With the print adjustments in the Print section you are more or less changing what the printer does when the same numerical RGB value is sent to the printer driver. Ideally the printer should be using an appropriate ICC profile so that neutral values in the Print section result in the printer output looking like the same image rendered on the computer's monitor. But if an appropriate profile is not available or not giving consistent results, then the print adjustments can be used to get in the ballpark. It probably won't be as accurate as a proper profile, but it might be good enough.

With soft proofing, you are limiting the possible RGB values displayed on your monitor by the viewing application to those which the printer, when already properly profiled, is capable of reproducing. That is, you are translating all of the RGB values in the picture to those within the printer's color gamut before then sending those numbers to the monitor and ultimately the printer.

Soft proofing is built upon the premise that the printer is already properly profiled. If the adjustments in the Print section are altered after the printer has been profiled, then the profile will no longer be accurate. (Note that the use of different papers with the same printer require different profiles for each type of paper.)

Comment: Just to add to this, in your case where you you want to generate a jpg for later printing then you may want to adjust things using soft proofing and  the profile for the eventual printer and paper you will print on. It does however depend on how the InDesign software manages colours.